# Как совершать мат действия в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует словарь `b={'One':1}`, в котором ключ это какое-то слово, а значение приходит из отдельного .txt файла .Я пытался делать так:

```
if (b['One']) = 1:
print ('ok')
```

Но ничего не получается, я думаю может из-за того данные из файла .txt идут списком. Как исправить это недоразумение? Спасибо.

```
with open ('R2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
keys = f.readlines()

with open ('R1.txt' , encoding='utf-8') as f2:
values = f2.readlines()

all = {}


for i in range(len(keys)):
all[keys[i]] = values[i]


if (int(all['One'])) > 10000 :
    print("Ok")
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////

```
with open ('R1.txt' , encoding='utf-8') as f2:
     values = f2.readlines()
b= str(values)
y=b.replace("'", "")
m=y.replace("\n", "")
print(m)
```

Comment: а может переводы строк мешают? и проверка на равенство == , а просто равно - присваивание. и из файла приходит текст, а не число. могу еще погадать :)

Comment: Непонятно. Если словарь уже существует, то причем тут отдельный файл?

Comment: Смотрю, хоть и "непонятно", но это не помешало написать ответ :))

Comment: Давайте весь код. Эти две строки с тремя ошибками ни о чём не говорят.

Comment: @splash58 это я сделал квалифицированное предположение (уже после комментария) 

Answer (score 3):

Для начала в сравнении используются два знака == : `if (b['One']) == 1:`

Если значения взяты из файла, то они наверняка строка, а не число (узнать можно выведя словарь на экран `print(b)`). Поэтому попробуйте или сравнивать со строкой

```
if (b['One']) == '1':
```

Или конвертировать значение в число перед сравнением (опасно - программа может аварийно завершиться, если там окажется не число)

```
if (int(b['One'])) == 1:
```

Но еще лучше конвертировать строку в число сразу при считывании данных и присвоении ключам словаря.

Comment: Я изменил вопрос, теперь там весь код. В ['One'] находятся цифры по типу 29'999 , и при этом int() не работает у меня

Comment: 29'999 это сколько?

Comment: Это двадцать девять тысяч девятьсот девяносто девять

Comment: Вот так с апострофом и записано?

Comment: Да, так и записанно

Comment: Значит, нужно убирать этот апостроф, потому что в записи чисел апостроф не используется.

Comment: апостроф я пробовал убрать с помощью re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s) но почему то не работает, с помощью чего это еще можно сделать?

Comment: .replace("'","")

Comment: Я добавил еще кода в вопрос, апостроф убрать получилось, но вот есть такая штука как "\n", и вот она не убирается, с помощью .replace() можно убрать или там только единоразово можно убирать?

Comment: @Tryr, `.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'one': 1} 
b = int("29'999".replace("'", ""))

if a['one'] == b:
    print("Да равно")
else:
    print("Нет не равно")
```

Comment: код не читабелен, исправьте табуляцию